# What is the ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I keep reading tutorials where I'm supposed to enter something into the ADB command line and that it's in my Android sdk/platform-tools. So I find it, click on it, and a black screen comes up for about 2 seconds and while it's up, it scrolls through a bunch of text. So how am I supposed to use this "adb"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called the Android Debug Bridge, and the Android Developers Site documentation does a better job of explaining it than I can:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

If you are looking for the adb command line, navigate to `<sdk>/platform-tools/` and run

```
adb.exe shell
```

from the command line.

Comment: I have that page open. It's the one telling me to use a command line.

Comment: You need to use command line (Windows) or Shell (Linux) to use adb... it is a command line software

Comment: Ok so I tried that and I get "error: device not found" in the cmd.

Comment: Make sure you enable device debugging in your phone: `Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging` for me

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that is well documented since day 1 on the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

> Android Debug Bridge (adb) is a versatile command line tool that lets
>   you communicate with an emulator instance or connected Android-powered
>   device. It is a client-server program that includes three components:
>
> A client, which runs on your development machine. You can invoke a
>   client from a shell by issuing an adb command. Other Android tools
>   such as the ADT plugin and DDMS also create adb clients. A server,
>   which runs as a background process on your development machine. The
>   server manages communication between the client and the adb daemon
>   running on an emulator or device. A daemon, which runs as a background
>   process on each emulator or device instance.

So plain old English, ADB can be found on %ANDROID_HOME%/platform-toos/, and it's this magical command line that allows you to comunicate with your mobile device, either a physical or a Virtual device (AVD),  so whenever you deploy you are passing the application through the device thanks to the ADB on a specific client port on your computer to the daemon port on the device.

**Interesting things you can do with it?**

- Logcat: ./adb logcat allows you to see the log trace of each proces.
- Install: ./adb install  allows you to install apk to the device.
- Killing:./adb kill-sever
- Starting:./adb stat-server
- Enter SQLite3: adb -s your_device shell
- Use the monkey:  adb shell monkey -v -p your.app.package 500 to
  generate random events

And a lot more! Read the documentation it's beatiful and self-explanatory.