# how adb install and work it inorder to use shell android?

Tags: android, shell, adb

How do I install ADB? What do I need to do in order to get to the shell on an android phone?

I installed the SDK, and now I am using Eclipse. How do I install apps using ADB?

Comment: Use this stackoverflow Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146925/what-is-the-adb

Answer (score 1):

Go To

->Android->android-sdk->platform-tools>adb.exe from command prompt

It will give you a list of options how to use it adb

To install apk from adb

```
adb install myapk.apk(path to apk)
```

For other ADB commands info check this link

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/android_adb_commandsummary.html

Answer (score 1):

right click "computer" -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Then add `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` to the end of your System Path variable. **Make sure your at the end of the whole path variable so you don't overwrite what is currently there**

Then open up command window and type `adb install apkLocation\myApp.apk`

Comment: tnx,but first i copy a apk file to tmp then install it with adb and it works well.